# Android Connecting to MySQL Database Remotedly

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-intent

How to Connect Android with MySQL Database Remotely?
My Requirement is to Connect MySQL Database from Android Application and fetch one column related values from MySQL Table and display the column values on Android Screen?

Could any one tell me the best solution?

Comment: The "best solution" would depend so much on what your goal is. Simple? Secure? Fast? Maintainable? All of the above?

Comment: The Application should be fast

Comment: It will be so bad in terms of security since the database password will be stored as a plaintext in your app. A better solution is to connect to a web server. The web server is the one that connect with the database. Your app only knows how to request and retrieve results. You can do RESTFul web services and have the data returned as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

Write simple JDBC code with the connection string of your remote DB. If you are trying to write an application on android, which should connect to a remote DB then your remote db should be hosted on a public server. Once you know the public IP, port, dbinstance, username, password then you can create a connection URL and then to create a connection do something like this:

```
dbConnection = DriverManager.getConnection("Your remote db conn url", "DB_USER","DB_PASSWORD");
```

Answer (score 0):

> How to Connect Andriod with MySQL Database Remotedly? My Requirement
>   is to Connect MySQL Database from Andriod Application and fetch one
>   column related values from MySQL Table and display the column values
>   on Andriod Screen?
>
> Could any one tell me the best solution?

I think the best solution is to create some `PHP` scripts, then call requests on these scripts from Android application. They'll return to you `JSON` that will contain specific data. Finally, try to parse `JSON` and do some stuff you like with it.IT

**Pseudo-code:**

```
private static final String GET_ITEMS_URL = "http://domainname.com/scripts/getitems.php";
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(GET_ITEMS_URL);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
if (entity != null) {
   String jsonString = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
   if (jsonString.length() > 0) {
      return new JSONObject(jsonString);
   }
   return null;
}
```